# Zwei Fliegen mit einer Klappe schlagen

Tags: etymology, idiom

Die Bedeutung der Redewendung

> Zwei Fliegen mit einer Klappe schlagen

ist mir klar – man erledigt zwei Dinge mit einer Aktion.

Aber woher kommt in diesem Zusammenhang der Begriff *Klappe?* Ist es nur ein anderer Begriff für *(Fliegen)klatsche* oder bedeutet es etwas anderes?

Comment: In Österreich und der Schweiz ist die Variante zwei Fliegen auf einen Streich schlagen gebräuchlich. Bei den Märchen der Gebrüder Grimm hat das tapfere Schneideleiern auch sieben auf einen Streich erlegt. Leider hilft das im Sinne von Klappe nicht weiter :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Klappe ist in diesem Zusammenhang das Gleiche wie "Klatsche", nur dass diese Begriffe aus verschiedenen Regionen kommen.

Auch Sprichwörter ändern sich durch Regionen. Wir in Österreich sagen z.B. "Zwei Fliegen auf einen Streich" oder "Zwei Fliegen auf einen Schlag".

Wobei all diese Wörter bzw. Sprichwörter das Gleiche meinen: Zwei Probleme mit einer Lösung lösen.

Die Herkunft ist nicht genau bekannt, jedoch tippen mehrere Quellen auf die Herkunft von einem Märchen der Gebrüder Grimm (Das tapfere Schneiderlein).

[http://uli.söhnel.info/redewendungen/135.php](http://uli.s%C3%B6hnel.info/redewendungen/135.php)

> Die Redensart ist entweder Anlass für eine Episode
>   im Märchen vom tapferen Schneiderlein der Gebrüder Grimm gewesen, oder
>   sie hat sich erst sekundär daraus gebildet. Bekanntlich gelingt dem
>   Schneiderlein die Großtat, gleichzeitig sieben Fliegen mit einer
>   Klappe zu schlagen.

Answer (score 5):

Eine simple Suche nach *Fliegenklappe* ergibt genug Treffer, um zu behaupten, dass diese Bezeichnung gebräuchlich ist.

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fliegenklappe

https://www.google.de/search?q=fliegenklappe&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X

Zur Herkunft:

> Ihr historischer Ursprung lässt sich nicht genau bestimmen, da es schon früher mehrere ähnliche Redensarten gab. Wahrscheinlich ist jedoch, dass es eine Verbindung mit den Märchen der Brüder Grimm gibt. Bekanntlich gelingt es dem tapferen Schneiderlein sieben Fliegen auf einen Streich zu erlegen.

[[Quelle](http://deutschhappen.com/deutsche-sprichworte-zwei-fliegen-mit-einer-klappe-schlagen)]

Also höchstwahrscheinlich (eigene Vermutung) entstand diese Version des Sprichwortes, nachdem die Fliegenklappe erfunden wurde ;)

Comment: Ok, vielleicht ist das ein regional unterschiedlich gebräuchliches Wort - mir ist _Fliegenklappe_ überhaupt nicht bekannt. Eine kurze Suche bei z.B. Amazon nach einem solchen Artikel findet auch fast nichts, im Gegensatz zur _Fliegenklatsche_.

Comment: Möglich ist auch, dass sich ein regional entstandenes Sprichwort auf die ganze Republik ausgeweitet hat.